# useFactory does not get the value

Tags: angular

I am trying to set the locale through `useFactory`. In the service, there is an API call made which assigns the value to `_locale` on the basis of some condition. Now, the issue is in `useFactory: (localeService: LocaleService) => localeService._locale`, it is getting undefined.
I get this error:

```
message: InvalidPipeArgument: 'locale.toLowerCase is not a function' for pipe 'CurrencyPipe' , Error: InvalidPipeArgument: 'locale.toLowerCase is not a function' for pipe 'CurrencyPipe'
```

If I simply set a variable in my service and use it as `_locale` then it works fine but here is an API call being made which causes this problem. How can I tackle this problem? Its just that it needs to wait till the response is returned and assigned to `_locale`.

This is my locale service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { SystemSettingsService } from 'src/app/system-settings/system-settings.service';
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import localeDe from '@angular/common/locales/de';
import localeDeExtra from '@angular/common/locales/extra/de';


@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class LocaleService {

    public _locale: string;
    public _localeSettings: any;

    constructor(private systemSettings: SystemSettingsService) {
       this.getLocaleSettings();
    }

    getLocaleSettings() {
        this.systemSettings.getLocale().subscribe((data) => {
            this._localeSettings = data;
            this.setLocale();
        });
    }

    setLocale() {
        if (this._localeSettings.format === 1) {
            this._locale = 'de-De';
            registerLocaleData(localeDe, 'de-DE', localeDeExtra);
        } else if (this._localeSettings.format === 2) {
            this._locale = 'en-US';
        }
    }
}
```

This is my module

```
import { NgModule, LOCALE_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule, CurrencyPipe } from '@angular/common';
import { LocaleService } from './locale.service';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
    ],
    providers: [CurrencyPipe, {
      provide: LOCALE_ID,
      deps: [LocaleService],
      useFactory: (localeService: LocaleService) => localeService._locale
    }]
})
export class MyModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would first change the _locale to a static variable:

```
static _locale: string;
```

then change the useFactory to return the function that sets it:

```
  useFactory: (localeService: LocaleService) => localeService.getLocaleSettings()
```

troubleshooting, put in a console.log to see if the function is being called.

```
 getLocaleSettings() {
        this.systemSettings.getLocale().subscribe((data) => {
            this._localeSettings = data;
            console.log('data = ', data);
            this.setLocale();
        });
    }
```

Comment: message: InvalidPipeArgument: 'locale.toLowerCase is not a function' for pipe 'CurrencyPipe' , Error: InvalidPipeArgument: 'locale.toLowerCase is not a function' for pipe 'CurrencyPipe'

Comment: I get this error.

Comment: can you try changing your function getLocaleSettings to use await instead of subscribe?

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work.

Comment: I didn't realize your getLocaleSetting function doesn't return a promise. Try the updated answer to see if that works.

Comment: I tried that already, didn't work.

Comment: if you put in a console.log in the getLocaleSetting function. Do you see the log?

Comment: yes, on the other side if I put a console.log(localeService._locale) in the useFactory, it gives undefined.